# How can I access to the value of the row in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I access to the value of the row in GridView ?

I could access to the `SelectedValue` but I wonder how can I access to for example `MyGridView.Rows[4].Value`!

**Note**: The value is an ID and doesn't appear in the Grid (doesn't exist as a cell).

Comment: Where does that value comes from if it's not in the grid?

Comment: I think he means its not visible

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataKeyNames property ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)) of the GridView as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="rowID"></asp:GridView>
```

You can then access in code-behind:

```
int rowID = (int)MyGridView.DataKeys[4].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row_Index].Cells[column_Index].Value
```

For the love of god, please don't use magic numbers like "4", define constants for the row/column indices

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting values in `RowCommand event` but you can access in other place as well using same logic

```
protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
       GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
       TextBox txt = (TextBox)row.FindControl(""); // now you row object and you can 
                                                     access all of you controls
    }        
}
```